# What criteria distinguish a hypothetical from legal advice?

Tags: discussion, legal-advice

As an example, how would one characterize [this](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/putting-farm-you-do-not-own-into-a-living-trust) question?...hypothetical as is, or across the legal advice line?

Just looking for some broad themes here...

Answer (score 3):

Here's one criterion: ***The absence of sufficient information to provide legal advice.***

E.g., in the example question the state (in fact, even the country) is not specified.

Another criterion met in this case, even if enough information were provided to admit competent legal advice: ***The question amends itself to good answers that do not provide legal advice.***

Of course, no answer on this subject is complete without referencing the authoritative discussion of this question: [Policy for questions that clearly ask for specific legal advice](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/221/10)