# How do I ask a general law question?

Tags: discussion, legal-advice

[On paragraph 3 of this page](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), it says:

> *"Please don't ask questions seeking legal advice on a specific matter. These are off-topic for Law Stack Exchange."*

What does this rule imply about how to phrase my question about the law in a learning forum such as this one?

Answer (score 7):

### Make the question about the law rather than about individuals

For example:

> I shot a guy, am I guilty of murder?

is clearly seeking legal advice. However:

> What is the definition of murder in [some jurisdiction]?

is a question about the law which may answer the first question but it is not legal advice.

Answer (score 6):

## Short Answer

> **Make it hypothetical.**

### Explanation

To ask a hypothetical question, use these helpful tips:

- State it. *"This is a hypothetical."* *"Hypothetical example."* *"Hypothetical facts."* Or just simply:  *"Hypothetical:"*
- Replace first person pronoun references like "I" and "we" with either

  - Third person pronouns like "he", "she", "it" and "they"
    ...or (even better)
  - [Metasyntactic variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable) like "A", "B", "C", etc.
- Delete any references to any specific case or case number, etc.