# Question closed without any real information why?

Tags: support, close-reasons

My question was closed as being off-topic, but no explanation was given. Please help me. The question is [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/79335/uk-fence-border-height-part-of-harassment-campaign).

It asked about the law on fence heights. As of now the council have failed to reply within their stated 2 weeks. It appears they will allow it with no response. (They have done similar things in the past where they do not put his activity on record; his fake road signs mimicking real ones allowing them to stay for over a year, draping logs on the road and never responding to acknowledge they are there ultimately causing debris on the road when a verge trimmer destroyed them, putting a bin on the road causing buses to stop and move it, causing rats and all day fires, etc. One year he would set off his cockerel aggitating it every time we went in our garden. This would go on for hours. Another neighbour complained and we had retaliation against us. The council confirmed someone else had complained, but about a month later when the retaliation was continuing, we phoned the council again and all record of the complaint about the cockerel by another person was deleted from council records.).

My present question showed how the neighbour was setting up situations to falsely justify the increase in height of this fence. They set up a situation again yesterday. Feigning shock as we pulled out of our drive in a car, then running up their garden in front of their CCTV cameras.

What I could add to the question is every time we are aware he is up to one of his con tricks, we take off our CCTV footage that shows our garden and shows we are doing nothing wrong. Sometimes we even have hand-held video showing they are setting up incidents and acting wrongfully themselves.

Answer (score 6):

You write:

> My question was closed as being off-topic, but no explanation was given.

However, an explanation **was** given.The key part of the close reason reads:

> Questions that clearly ask for specific legal advice are off-topic. For more information, see [Policy for questions that clearly ask for specific legal advice](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/221).

That policy post, liunked in the close reason for your question, and again in my answer, lists four warning signs that a question **might** constitute a request gfort legal advice. Your question fits three of them. Those signs are listed as:

> - They [such questions] use pronouns that indicate a personal relationship
>   "My mother was involved in an accident around the corner from my house..."

> - They contain highly emotive language
> - They explicitly ask "What should I do?" or something similar in the question
> - The only answer that you could safely give is "You should engage the services of a lawyer/attorney"

Perhaps even more importantly, your question has all the signs of another common category here on Law.SE, which i call "Look what they done to me".  In this category, the OP spends much of the question explaining how unjust or evil the actions of those opposed to the poster have been, trying to convince readers to "side" with the OIP, or the protagonist of the OP's story.
.
Such a story may well be true. But it is not the purpose of Law.SE to sort out who is right in individual disputes, nor are we equipped to do so. Nor is it our purpose to advise individuals what they should do in a particular situation. In fact such advice is absolutely forbidden.

What we can do and often do do is to explain what the law permits, and what it requires. What rights a person has in a particular situation, and possibly what legal avenues are available. But a post that spends most of its efforts on explaining how evil or unjust one side of a dispute has been is not likely to get much attention, and is much more likely to get closed, even though that is not a formal close reason.

What a poster might better do is describe the situation in more objective terms, and ask whether the law permits the parties involved to act as they have done and where there are legal methods for bringing the dispute to a more neutral forum. That someone here might be able to answer usefully.

In fact, I suggest that a (probably shorter) version of this be added to the [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) ropic in the help center, or perhaps become a separate topic in the help center.

I do not have the rights to edit the help center, and I wouldn't do so without consensus even if I did, but do othets agree that such an addition would be a good idea?

Comment: btw, just interesting, another question, https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/78970/can-i-get-reimbursed-if-police-shot-the-window-of-my-car-during-a-standoff have some of that signs, but it is not closed. why? it is on top in the month tab. and see the end of your answer, it is cut off.

Comment: @qdinar
 My answer was accidentally saved unfinished, and the thread was delet4ed seconds later, so that I was not able to save a completed version. I have now finished it. See the history. As for the post you link to, it does have some of the characteristics of a RSLA. Whether to close a post for that or any reason is always a judgement call, and so far no one has acted to close that post See  https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1185/excessive-use-of-specific-legal-advice-closure-reason for some debates on similar questions.

Comment: It is also very detailed to a specific circumstance and an answer might not be generally helpful.