# Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes (volume 07/2023 — today)

Tags: discussion

Let me analogize [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34447).

[Does (Ontario's) Consumer Protection Act, 2002 protect Consumers travelling on the Toronto Transit Commission? Why or why not?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/93468)
[Did Instagram breach Business Practices and Consumer Protection Act, SBC 2004?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/93481)

ought be reopened, because they do not "clearly ask for specific legal advice". Don't hesitate to [edit them further](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1188).

Answer (score 2):

### Preface

We do not have such a queue. Such a thread does not have community backing. This Stack is tiny and there are about two dozen users that participate more than occasionally.

### Those questions don't warrant reopening as they are.

These questions were written in a fashion that is explicitly banned as requesting legal advice. No substantial change was made to make them not appear to be such.

Both questions were moderator-closed. So there are heavy quality issues.

The second question is an attempt to re-create a question that was asked with the exact same picture prior, which was closed or deleted for some reason.