# When to migrate questions from Security.SE?

Tags: discussion, migration

Security.StackExachange mainly exists to talk about hacking and hacking prevention. As you might expect, questions about what's legal and whether someone should press changes come up quite frequently. Our usual response is to close the question with a comment "You need to hire a laywer dude. We can't help you".

Somebody recently asked in a [meta.security.SE question](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2466/61443) whether our Help Center should include a link to Law.SE. The accepted answer [disclaimer: mine] basically says "I'm pretty sure that Law.SE is not a free laywer service, so they may be ok with general legal thought-experiments, but let's not send them specific people's specific problems".

Questions:

1. Do you guys agree with what was said in the meta.security.SE post?
2. Where do you draw the line between "interesting thought-experiment" and "your specific problem"?

Answers to those would help us make rules for which questions we close, and which we migrate to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a tricky problem: Legally we can't offer legal advice, but we can and do provide legal information.  [These posts try to help people understand where we draw the line](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal-advice?sort=votes).

I personally think that your summary response is appropriate.

You should feel free to migrate posts that ask legal questions without asking for legal advice.

Of those remaining: Many questions asking for legal advice can be "genericized" so as to ask for legal information.  But that takes work, so my preference would be that if in a close reason or comment the asker is directed to Law.SE as a possible forum, they be specifically directed to something like [this post](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/221/10) which explains that they will have to rework the question for it to be on-topic.

Comment: I agree with my noble and learned friend ;)

Comment: Great, that clears it up very nicely :)

Comment: Would https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/79237/legitimate-ways-to-release-an-unpaid-mortgage also qualify for migration to here?

Comment: @WGroleau: No, it would be closed here as asking for specific legal advice.