# Can questions about how to break the law and get away with it on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are there laws against such kind of discussions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, someone who provides advice to further the commission of a crime, or prevent its prosecution, can be charged with "aiding and abetting," or as an "accessory" or "conspirator."  So anything that could be construed as participation in or solicitation of an *actual* crime is not allowed here.

Note that a lawyer can't advise a client to break the law, and [in various circumstances](http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/the-crime-fraud-exception-the-attorney-client-privilege.html) a lawyer has professional and official responsibilities to notify authorities of *intended* crimes.

Fortunately, not only does Law.SE *not* provide legal advice, but also [requests for legal advice are considered off-topic](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/221/10).

Even in the U.S. it is possible to run afoul of the law by [communicating certain information](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/9044/10).  A request for illegal information would certainly be off-topic.

So what's left?  At least in the U.S., it is not *generally* forbidden to discuss the elements of a crime and how the law enforcement system works and might be frustrated in finding and proving them.  So, for example, the classic, "I'm writing a book and a character commits crime *X*.  Could he get away with it by doing *Y*?" is not *a priori* off topic.  Or, for example, "Could *A* have gotten away with murder if he had just done *Z*?"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So in short the answer is yes, but not in a specific case. Let's say, a question saying "How park illegally avoiding the tickets?" would be ok.

Comment: @GabrielDiego - Sort of.  "How can I avoid parking tickets while parking illegally" would be closed as too broad.  But even specific cases need not be off-topic.  For example, "Suppose I illegally store classified data on a personal email server; could I get away with it by blaming my IT guy?" is not only specific but also a real-world case, but at this point answers could not help any people charged with that crime to actually avoid prosecution, *and* it could elicit answers that deal with more general legal principles and hence are of *broader* interest.