# Is asking "what are my legal options in this case" on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I have a situation where I might contemplate to proceed via legal ways.

Would the question "I have this situation, what are my options/how should I proceed to use them" on topic here?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, since the [tour] and [disclaimer](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/disclaimer) explicitly says "The answers you get here are not a substitute for legal advice, and the other contributors here aren't acting as your lawyer."

Comment: @AndrewT. that's why I am asking here first. I accept the fact that I am not receiving official legal advice, but I have the feeling that asking how to obtain it is on-topic? e.g.: https://law.stackexchange.com/q/31117/5779

Comment: Perhaps [Policy for questions that clearly ask for specific legal advice](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/221) which is linked on "specific legal advice" close reason might help... reading this, that question might be off-topic. Unfortunately, I'm not a regular here, and I can't see if that question has pending close votes or not...

Comment: If you decide to post a question, don't forget to specify your jurisdiction (country or, if in the U.S., state). That helps us narrowing down the applicable law and --when possible-- directing you (with URL links) to court opinions that are likely relevant toward assessing the situation you describe.

Comment: @IñakiViggers my main question is exactly that, I don't know which jurisdiction would apply. I will post in the next minutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would emphasize that the [Q&A pointed to in the comments by Andrew](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/221/10) are still the standard.

As a practical matter, I can point out some trivial changes to the form of your question that would make it seem less like a request for specific legal advice:

- Say, "Here is a hypothetical situation..."; *not* "I have this situation...."
- Ask for legal *information*, not *advice*.  "What *should* I do?" is a request for advice (and opinion, which is also off-topic...).

Answer (score 5):

When I was a Court official, we were allowed to answer "What are my legal options here?" (being factual) but absolutely not "How should I proceed to use them/which option is the best/ what should I do here?" (being legal advice), though many litigants could not see the difference. I would think the same applies here, for the same reasons.