# What is purpose of this site if my relevant question isn't acceptable?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

I had asked it on Interpersonal stack exchange but they suggest me to ask here on Law stack exchange.
My question is about law and I don't think it's off-topic?
Here is my question
[Should I file a case against people who bothering and harassing my family?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/33219/should-i-file-a-case-against-people-who-bothering-and-harassing-my-family)
I wonder need to ask for attention of beta on meta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As presently written it's very hard to decipher the text of that question.  But all questions I can discern are of the form, "What can I do to use the law to punish specific people for specific actions?"  That sounds like a request for specific legal advice.

Even if it weren't closed for that reason, I would also vote to close the question as being too unclear.

Comment: I'm not looking for specific advice but just what I can claim and action take against them or what penal codes they are deserved.

Comment: So you *are* asking for specific legal advice, then.

Comment: @Swapnil – there is a lot of discussion about the [meta-tag:legal-advice] restriction that might help you.  I like the way [one user put it yesterday](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/738/10) (Paraphrasing): "If it's a question appropriate for a consultation with a lawyer (or prosecutor) in your jurisdiction, then you should do that and not ask it here."

Comment: @feetwet I have deleted my question and asked another one that's definitely not off topic.