# Why was this answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, moderation, deleted-answers

https://law.stackexchange.com/a/63647/12871

It seems that advising someone to get a lawyer is the correct course when a user asks for specific advice on how to handle their taxes.

Answer (score 4):

That post should be a comment at best, as it does not answer the question.

This alone is enough to make it delete-worthy.

The fact that the question should have been closed, and the post adds nothing useful to make it worth saving, means it should be deleted to stop it interfering with regular clean-up processes; some naïve but well-meaning user is likely to upvote it, so Roomba will skip over the question instead of removing it.

Answer (score 3):

The deleted answer read, in full:

> You need to talk to a lawyer, not a random bozo on the Internet.

That's not an answer; that's generic advice.

On Law.SE the "correct course" when someone asks for specific [legal-advice](/questions/tagged/legal-advice) is either:

1. Vote to close >> select "A community-specific reason" >> then "Questions that ask for specific legal advice are off-topic.  For more information, see [Policy for questions that clearly ask for specific legal advice](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221/policy-for-questions-that-clearly-ask-for-specific-legal-advice)."
2. Edit the post so that it is not a request for specific legal advice.

Comment: I don't see anything in the linked pages that says we shouldn't respond with a recommendation to seek legal advice. Even if that rule existed, it doesn't seem to be the reason this answer was deleted, as the mod left up another answer also directing OP to get a lawyer.

Comment: @bdb484 The answer that was not deleted contains answers to elements of the question.

Comment: If the idea of the policy is to protect the OP "from loss due to following incomplete advice, or advice from amateur legal enthusiasts," and to protect answering users from "exposing themselves to unauthorized practice of law or malpractice claims," it seems strange that we would remove answers that address those risks while retaining answers that increase them.