# What is wrong with my post

Tags: discussion, scope

I recently posted on law stack exchange. My last post has two votes to close. I do not understand why. I am hoping somebody here can tell me what the issues is. Here is a link to the post:

[Is this a conflict of interest for the lawyer](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/92523/is-this-a-conflict-of-interest-for-the-lawyer)

Comment: The policy on legal advice is not uniformly enforced due to the dynamics of community voting and different criteria by different moderators at different times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The close votes are because the voters believe your question is asking for individual legal advice, which the site rules do not allow. Although the question is written in neutral/hypothetical terms, the voters may guess (because of the specificity of detail) that you are one of the people in the given scenario and you are looking for legal advice about what you ought to do. That might or might not be true - which is why it takes five people to agree to close a question, of which only two have chimed in so far.

You can learn more about the rationale for this policy by reading [Policy for questions that clearly ask for specific legal advice](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221/policy-for-questions-that-clearly-ask-for-specific-legal-advice).